# Elasticsearch collapse by a field A, with top hit by field B, with results sorted by field C

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Suppose I have these documents in elasticsearch:

```
{"name":"alpha", "grp":1, "priority": 1}
{"name":"beta", "grp":1, "priority": 3}
{"name":"gamma", "grp":2, "priority": 5}
{"name":"zeta", "grp":2, "priority": 1}
```

I want to query my index and get a single hit per `grp`.

The hit of a `grp` must be the document with highest `priority` value.

My overall query needs to return all fields, and be sorted by `name`.

Sample output:

```
{"name":"beta", "grp":1, "priority": 3}
{"name":"gamma", "grp":2, "priority": 5}
```

Query `collapse` doesn't seem to do the trick as I would need to sort by `priority` rather than `name`.

> The collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per collapse key
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html

I feel like there must be some combination of aggregations that will get the result I'm looking for, but I'm bashing my head into a wall. Please help me!?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve it using collapse (yet), you can see the current progress here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/45646

Comment: Oh dear, that is a very good summary of the issue I'm hitting, thanks for linking it. Dissapointing they don't have any "here's a complicated workaround" solutions on the issue

Comment: yeah , the closest I could get with aggs was using top_hits : POST test_collapse/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "grps": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "grp",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "priority": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I feel like if a `bucket_sort` sorting by name could slot in there it would do it, but got an error trying to combine that with `top_hits` previously :(

Comment: Yeah, sadly there is no way to sort by top hit. I was able to generate a sorting field based on an aggregation, but will use all the documents instead of just the first one. I can only think on nasty solutions right now.